# Codeigniter setup with nginx for hmvc stucture

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

Can anyone done with **Codeigniter setup with nginx for hmvc stucture?**
Please help me on this, I try to setup up codeigniter HMVC structure on nginx. But fails to many times. Please suggest some wayt to configure it.

I am using php7.0-fpm.

My nginx config file is

```
server {
listen 80;
root /var/www/html/salsetrack;
index index.html index.htm index.php;
server_name local.sales-track.com;

location / {
# First attempt to serve request as file, then
# as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
#try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
index index.html index.php;
  try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
  expires 30d;
} 

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri =404; 
#Include Nginx’s fastcgi configuration
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
#Look for the FastCGI Process Manager at this location 
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

include fastcgi_params;
 fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
 fastcgi_index index.php;
 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

}

location @handler {
      rewrite / /index.php;
}}
```

Comment: what is your server OS? centOS?

Comment: No. It's ubuntu.

Comment: Are you aware of the typo in line 3?
root /var/www/html/ **salsetrack**;

Answer (score 0):

You can refer https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/ for nginx configuration for codeigniter.

Comment: Sorry Friends, It's an issue with Codeigniter session. Thank for your reply.